# R Retrieve column name under condition in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements

I have a matrix with 0 or 1 values. When a line has only one "1", I want to get in return the column name in which is the "1" value and in any other cases get "0". For the example below:

```
test <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),ncol=5)
colnames(test) <- c('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5')
```

Result should be:

```
     c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 result
[1,]  0  1  1  0  1 0
[2,]  1  0  0  0  0 c1
[3,]  0  0  0  1  0 c4
[4,]  1  0  1  0  1 0
[5,]  0  1  0  0  0 c2
[6,]  0  0  0  1  1 0
[7,]  1  0  0  0  0 c1
[8,]  0  0  1  0  0 c3
```

Comment: I will say this more elaborately so SO doesn't pick it up, but what have you tried? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
test <- matrix(c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0),ncol=5)
colnames(test) <- c('c1','c2','c3','c4','c5')

result <- data.frame(test, result = apply(test, 1, function(row){ if(sum(row)==1)colnames(test)[[which(row==1)]]else 0}))
```

Comment: Thx, double "[" are not necessary in  "[[which(row==1)]]"